# Error when trying to run HTML files using VS Code

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code

I was working on the CSS for my website and accidentally ran it, which opened a JSON file. Now, whenever I try to run any of my HTML files, a new tab is opened that says "unable to connect to local host". I’ve also tried running previous projects and they will not run. I get a message about opening a JSON file instead. Is there a way I can fix this?

I’ve tried reinstalling VS code but that didn’t do anything.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: http
    //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        
        {
            "command": "npm start",
            "name": "Run npm start",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "port": 9222,
        "request": "attach",
        "type": "chrome",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    ]
}
```

Comment: How are you "running" your HTML?

Comment: It is worth noting that one can neither run CSS nor can CSS magically turn into JSON.

Comment: @XboxOne I use the run and debug button, but that is now missing. I'm unsure if it has to do with my JSON configurations.

Comment: In the left sidebar? Probably, since you mentioned that it stopped working ever since a JSON file appeared, it may be that you have accidentally modified you run config. Can you edit your question to include your run config, since that seems to be the problem?

Comment: @XboxOne yes, in the left sidebar. I'm assuming that my configurations is the issue, and that I just confused it with my CSS turning into a JSON file. All that's left in the sidebar is a green button, and when I press the settings gear I am redirected to my JSON config.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To run an HTML file correctly, you just change this JSON section:

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

to:

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
}
```

---

Or you can use a local server like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to run an HTML file as URL `http://localhost/index.html`

Comment: I have tried running through the green button as well, but I get redirected to a blank page or a page that tells me my server is not connecting to the LocalHost.

Comment: Do you want to run only with HTML and CSS? or also run Node JS local server?

Answer (score 0):

In your config, `Launch Chrome`'s port is configured as 8080 but the debugger attaches to port 9222 as configured in `Attach to Chrome`. Maybe this discrepancy is the problem?